# Dudas con WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

¿Saludos a todos tengo el siguiente código PHP UPDATE la cual uso para modificar algunos datos de mi BD (MysQL) todo funciona muy bien tengo el siguiente asunto que el campo cedula_vecino, la cual tomo para hacer la sentencia de modificación en WHERE, no se me modifica, será porque lo tomo como WHERE?  y quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de que pueda realizar los cambios sin necesidad de colocar otro campo de referencia. En resumen; La verdad quisiera saber porque no hace la modificación del campo cedula_vecino y si es posible otra posibilidad.

```
elseif ($_GET['act']=='update') {
        if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['cedula_vecino'])) {
        
            $cedula_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cedula_vecino']));
            $nombres_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['nombres_vecino']));
            $nacio_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['nacio_vecino']));
            $genero_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['genero_vecino']));
            $cedula_inmueble  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cedula_inmueble']));
            $estudio_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['estudio_vecino']));
            $ocupacion_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['ocupacion_vecino']));
            $telefono_vecino  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['telefono_vecino']));

            $modificado_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

            
             $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE comunidad_vecino SET  
                                                                    nombres_vecino = '$nombres_vecino',
                                                                    nacio_vecino   = '$nacio_vecino',
                                                                    genero_vecino   = '$genero_vecino',
                                                                    cedula_inmueble = '$cedula_inmueble',
                                                                    estudio_vecino = '$estudio_vecino',
                                                                    ocupacion_vecino = '$ocupacion_vecino',
                                                                    telefono_vecino = '$telefono_vecino',
                                                                    modificado_user  = '$modificado_user'
                                                              WHERE cedula_vecino = '$cedula_vecino'")
                                                or die('error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

    
                if ($query) {
                  
                    header("location: ../../main.php?module=vecino&alert=2");
                }         
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿tienes algun mensaje de error que te entregue MySql? ¿haces el UPDATE en una transaccion?

Comment: Si lo piensas bien, casi nunca tiene sentido modificar el campo del WHERE, generalmente es la llave primaria de la tabla y no debería ser editable. Además, si coincide con el WHERE es porque el dato ya tiene el contenido con el que intentarías actualizarlo, a no ser que quieras cambiarlo por otra cosa en cuyo caso debes expresarlo en la parte del `SET`

Comment: Si que se puede actualizar el campo que uses en el where, por lo si hay un error puede venir de otra parte. De todas formas, si quieres poner que versión de mysql gastas para ver si en esa hay algún problema... Una solución que puedes adoptar es, si esa tabla tiene un identificador único, hacer una primera consulta para buscar el id y después actualizar poniendo como cláusula WHERE ese id. Un saludo.